# Ruby on Rails Activerecord 'where' for array filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord

I have a `Meal` model with an `ingredients` attribute. The ingredients attribute is a multidimensional array eg. `ingredients: => [[ 1, 5, "g"], [ 2, 5,"ml"], [3, 10,"tsp"]]`. The first value in each inner array is an ingredient id.

My search params give an array of ingredient ids, eg. `ingredients"=>["3", "67"]`

I know I can iterate through all the meals and compare with the search parameters with `.each do` etc, but I would like to use `.where` so I can better limit results. Is this possible?

I'm not sure how to select the first item of each inner array to compare with the search parameters. I have tried a few variations but either get formatting errors or no results.

If `search = ["3", "67"]` (example ingredient ids)

`Meal.where('ingredients IN (?)', "#{search}")` (No results)

`Meal.where('ingredients[][0] IN (?)', "#{search}")` (This gives an error)

Comment: Just going to put this out there. Down the line, you are going to hate yourself for not modelling your relational data using relations. The document storage features in Postgres are not a "neat way to save on some tables." Speaking from experience. ;-)

Comment: I looked into this but I was unsure whether it was the correct choice. Each meal has many ingredients, each ingredient with separate data (amount, units , etc). If I was to use a belongs_to has_many association,  new ingredients would be created for each meal and this would make the database grow VERY rapidly as duplicate ingredients would be made but with different data. The way I have done it, I have 1 set of ingredients and the database stays small. [This](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) 'appears' to confirm what I'm thinking. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why would you create new ingredients for each meal? The way you do this is to have a separate table for ingredients and reuse the existing ones. The relation between these entities would be many-to-many (N:M), meaning that any ingredient can belong to any one or more meals and any meal can contain any number of ingredients. That way you wouldn't create new say "potato" ingredient for each meal that contains potatoes, you would just reuse an existing potato since it can belong to multiple meals. The amount of each ingredient can be handled in a join table with a `:through` param

Comment: Basically you would have a model in between meals and ingredients which would link those together along with a `unit` and `amount` properties. That would achieve the same thing you have here but in a relational way and would make your life way easier with AR.  docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many